# readymade docker image for tensorflow to predownload

Tags: docker, tensorflow, docker-image

Is there a readymade docker image for pre installed tensorflow available for downloading in advance? I know about gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow. However as I know it you have to run docker to first download it. I think eventual runs happen from the already downloaded copy.

I want to download it manually in advance for using later. I tried:

```
$ docker image pull gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

but it gave me error:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.32/images/create?fromImage=gcr.io%2Ftensorflow%2Ftensorflow&tag=latest: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Comment: haven't you forgotten a `sudo`in your command ?

Comment: @Xatyrian: aghh... thanks for pointing out. I was trying out way too many things and missed it in my last attempt :( That solved the problem. I was thinking that there was some error on repository side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your user should have the `docker` group assigned. The docker service has to run on that machine as well.

Assuming you're on a linux machines, to add the group, you can simply execute:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USERNAME
```

To save the image on your machine, you can execute the following command:

```
docker save --output image.tar $IMAGE
```

NOTE: the file can be big, so I suggest to run also

```
gzip -9 image.tar
```

---

Another version of this command is:

```
docker save $IMAGE | gzip > myimage.tgz
```

I forgot to mention that on the other machine you'll have to `load` this image.

```
gunzip -c myimage.tgz | docker load
```

---

For more info:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/

Comment: not sure whether it was required. the sudo worked in my case. However I was hoping that I can pull the image and share / copy around for other machines and users. But I guess that is not how docker images and repositories work...

Comment: I'm not a great fan of using `root` for docker. I prefer to have a specific user for my images. I've updated my answer.

Comment: your trick of save and load is helpful in my case. However I still need a sudo for all this. I am assuming that in your *sudo usermod -a -G docker $USERNAME* it is rather *$USER*. Also I am assuming that *$IMAGE* is the docker image I am working with.

Comment: I should have mentioned that those values need to be replaced.

Comment: Anyway if your issue is solved, I'd appreciate if you accept the answer

Comment: I can accept your answer if you add *sudo* to all your docker commands since that is the only it worked for me in spite of the usermod that you had suggested for making it work without sudo.

Comment: but it's not needed. If you set the user group properly, all the other commands will work without sudo. After you set the group restart the shell or the commands don't work.